# Linq Query Using Not In A Separate Table

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning `Linq` and I have a situation where I want to write my query like this

```
Select ordernumber 
from orders
where ordernumber not in (Select ordernumber 
                          from shipdata)
```

I know this will work in MS SQL Server, but how would I write this in LINQ?

Comment: Can you please update your post to include what you've tried and what the actual problem is you're having? As of now, you're asking for opinionated answers, asking us to write a `linq` query you've not tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this code is a list with 1 entry namely an Order with OrderNumber equals 1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqNotIn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
            {
                new Order { OrderNumber = 1 },
                new Order { OrderNumber = 2 }
            };

            List<ShipData> shipdata = new List<ShipData>
            {
                new ShipData { OrderNumber = 2 },
                new ShipData { OrderNumber = 3 }
            };

            var query = from o in orders
                        where !(from s in shipdata
                                select s.OrderNumber)
                               .Contains(o.OrderNumber)
                        select o;

            var result = query.ToList();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShipData
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have your syntax, but I get a compile error of ``Could not find an implementation fo the query pattern for source type 'orders'.  'Where' not found``

Comment: Strange. I've copied it from Visual Studio. Let me see.

Comment: Have you added the 'using System.Linq' at the top of your class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` method like below :

```
var result = from o in orders
where !((from sd in shipdata 
    select ordernumber).Contains(sd.ordernumber))
select o;
```

or you can use left join like below :

```
var result = from o in orders
 join sd in shipdata on o.ordernumber equals sd.ordernumber into sdx 
from sd in sdx.DefaultIfEmpty()
where sd == null
select o;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iIFc34)

Comment: Don't I want ``not contains``?  Since I want to see the ``ordernumbers`` that are in ``orders`` but not in ``shipdata``?

Comment: Is this valid C# syntax?  I am getting multiple compile errors when I put it into visual studio

Comment: He is assuming you have your entity classes created, do you?

Comment: @nalnpir - entity classes?  I've scaffolded the tables into Models.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: It should work if you have the namespace `System.Linq` added.

Comment: I have ``System.Linq`` and ``System.Linq.Expressions`` added

Comment: @jamesMandatory do you have a class for orders and one for shipdata?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean, can you show the models for those 2 classes?

Comment: @jamesMandatory added a fiddle sample

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the Lambda syntax so I can't help much with the query syntax. This is how I would write what you are looking for.

```
Orders.Where(order => !ShipData.Any(sd => sd.ordernumber == order.OrderNumber);
```

It should be noticed that Any will short circuit. Once it finds one match in Ship Data it will stop looking for more. Contains on the other hand will search every entry in Ship data.